# class not behaving as internal by default

Tags: c#, scope

When I define a class inside my c# windows application project, the class is supposed to be internally available to the project.

So I should be able to declare that type of class from within my form, without defining my class as a public class.

But I am getting an accessibility error, which goes away when my class is redefined as public, instead of the default (which is supposed to be internal to the assembly).

This is not a repeat question.  This question differs from other accessibility issues I have seen.

All items in my project (forms, classes, etc.) should belong to the same assembly, so what's going on?

Is default scope of class internal or not?  Research says its supposed to be internal, so this code is supposed to work....

I get...
"Inconsistent accessibility.  Field type Queue is less accessible than Form1.Queue"

See code below.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Queue Queue;          // <-- PROBLEM LINE

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

here is the definition of queue; i don't think its really important, but it was requested by a commenter; when I make the class Public, all problem is solved.  But that doesn't make sense if the default scope is supposed to be internal, it should not force me to make public:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    class Queue
    {
        private const int DEFAULTQUEUESIZE = 100;
        private int[] data;
        private int head = 0, tail = 0;
        private int numElements = 0;

        public Queue()
        {
            this.data = new int[DEFAULTQUEUESIZE];
        }

        public void Enqueue(int item)
        {
            if (this.numElements == this.data.Length)
            {
                throw new Exception("Queue full");
            }

            this.data[this.head] = item;
            this.head++;
            this.head = this.head % this.data.Length;
            this.numElements++;
        }

        public int Dequeue()
        {
            if (this.numElements == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Queue Empty");
            }

            int queueItem = this.data[this.tail];
            this.tail++;
            this.tail = this.tail % this.data.Length;
            this.numElements--;
            return queueItem;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: show definition of `Queue`

Comment: You cannot make an internal field publicly visible

Comment: You cannot expose a public property/field of an internal or private type.

Comment: That's not true, the default scope for classes is internal. After msdn:
>"Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can be either public or internal. Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified."

Comment: @V0ldek check table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels. it supports your statement,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by adding some guesswork to your question, if the type in question is

```
internal class Queue
```

then, quite obviously,

```
public Queue queue;
```

is an error - you have a `public` field of an `internal` type. How would you expect that to work? The problem is not that your `Form` has no access to `Queue`. It's that something from outside your project *has* access to the `Form`, *has* access to the `public` field, but it *does not have* access to the type of that field. That makes no sense, how do you expect an external class to make sense of a field whose type it cannot access?

If you declare the `Queue` as `public` - the problem goes away, the type is now externally visible.
If you declare the field as `internal` (or even `private`) - the error also goes away, as anything accessing that field also has access to the type.

I hope this explains the issue. On a side-note: declaring `public` fields is usually a mistake, if you want it to be accessible from the outside, use a property:

```
public Queue Queue {get; set;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed breakdown.  it helps me  understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your Form is declared `public` and contains a public field of your Queue class. Since `Queue` isn't public, the compiler refuses to compile your code. If you want `Queue` to be internal, declare the field as `internal` or `private`

Comment: even when i define as "internal" the problem doesn't go away.  it forces me to declare as public, then it goes away.  Besides, internal is supposed to be the default scope....

Comment: Maybe you missunderstood me. Take a look at V0ldeks answer. He explains what I meant more detailed.